# Only first letter of each row value being returned

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-call-interface

I'm having a bit of an issue with what is normally a simple foreach loop through a query array. I am trying to target individual field values from a row, but its only returning the first letter of each. New to OCI so any help would be appreciated.

```
$custcart = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM A113222813_CARTLINE WHERE CUST_ID=  
:cust_id");
oci_bind_by_name($custcart, ":cust_id", $_SESSION["CUST_ID"]);

if (!$custcart) {
    echo "There was an error. Please wait wwhile we redirect you.";
    $url ="login.php";
    $time_out = 5;
    header("refresh: $time_out; url=$url");
}

oci_execute($custcart);
include 'includes/header.php';

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($custcart, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo $item['CART_NAME'];

    }
}
```

Comment: before `foreach()` loop type `print_r($row)` and tell me the output

Comment: I get the following:  Array ( [CART_ID] => 1001 [CUST_ID] => 1061 [CART_NAME] => MORNING GROWLER [CART_QTY] => 12 [CART_DATE] => 12-MAR-14 [PRICE] => 7.99 ) 11M117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` is looping over all returned rows.  You are then `foreach` ing across that row and accessing the columns in the row (don't do that).  You just want the `while` and access `CART_NAME` in `$row`:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($custcart, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['CART_NAME'];
}
```

If you want to store the rows in an array to use more than once in the script, then:

```
while ($row[] = oci_fetch_array($custcart, OCI_ASSOC)) { }

//now or later

foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo $item['CART_NAME'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if I have multiple rows returned I would need a for each right?

Comment: If there is one row you can remove the while

Comment: @user2145682: The while is looping through all of the rows until there are no more.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for the idiocy but i've only ever used MySQL and PDO before!